# Model assumptions not met but model has predictive capabilities

Tags: predictive-models, assumptions

This is a general question, has probably been asked before (I searched and did not see similar), may have a simple answer, may be ridiculous, and is just to satisfy my own curiosity.

Say we build a linear model (or any model for that matter) on our training data, and then generate predictions from our test data and find that the model yields decent predictions as measured by say r^2.  We then test the assumptions of our model, find that it fails to meet necessary assumptions, and are either unable to manipulate our data meet the assumptions or  able to make our data to meet assumptions, but the new model built performs poorly compared to the invalid model.

Any reason (besides that of a theoretical standpoint) not to use  the better-performing invalid model, so long as it keeps generating accurate predictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't know about the use of `r^2` as a metric.  Second, you probably shouldn't be manipulating data to meet the assumptions of the model, but instead altering the model to conform to the data (or data-generating process, if known).  Third, if your goal is accurate prediction (you didn't say), then go ahead and use the model that gives you that, whether or not it is theoretically justified.
Now, given all that, if a simple, unprincipled model outperforms a more complex one, then you should spend a little time trying to figure out why exactly that is.  Some of the time that yields a model that is better than either.